# Extract Path from String in Array

Tags: php, simplexml

The Data come from a XML file to diplay them on a HTML site.
I need to extract only the Picture URL´s in " " from all  elemnts in my array for Output.
I have try that with preg_match but i dont get any result. What i doing wrong in my code?

```html
public function xmlParserPICtn():string
{
    
    $valuesPICtn = $this->xml->xpath("//OBJEKT[@ID='91727']//PICTURE"); 
    $searchpattern="@SRC=(.*)width@";
    preg_match($searchpattern, $valuesPICtn, $valuesPICt); //Search-String
    foreach ($valuesPICt as $PICelements) 
      {
             $display .= '<li>';
         $display .= ''.$PICelements->PIC.'';
         $display .= '</li>';
            
        }
     $display .= '';

      return $display;
  }
  
  
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OBJEKT ID="91727">
    
          <PICTURE ID="7">
              <ID>7</ID>
                  <PIC>&lt;IMG SRC="https://d1.cloudfront.net/00722.jpg" width="640" height="480" BORDER=0></PIC>
                 </PICTURE>
    
         <PICTURE ID="11">
              <ID>11</ID>
                  <PIC>&lt;IMG SRC="https://d1.cloudfront.net/01123.jpg" width="640" height="480" BORDER=0></PIC>
                 </PICTURE>
    
         <PICTURE ID="2">
                  <ID>2</ID>
                  <PIC>&lt;IMG SRC="https://d1.cloudfront.net/00224.jpg" width="640" height="480" BORDER=0></PIC>
                 </PICTURE>
    
         <PICTURE ID="9">
                  <ID>9</ID>
                  <PIC>&lt;IMG SRC="https://d1.cloudfront.net/00925.jpg" width="640" height="480" BORDER=0></PIC>
                 </PICTURE>
    
</OBJEKT>
```

Answer (score 0):

the first problem is variable name preg_match($searchpattern, **$valuesPICtnN**, $valuesPICt);  and correct is **$valuesPICtn**

Even so, it doesn't solve the final problem!!!!

As you have already converted the **XML** from string to object.

Just use the code below that I tested and it works.

```
$content = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><OBJEKT ID="91727"><PICTURE ID="7"><ID>7</ID><PIC>&lt;IMG SRC="https://d1.cloudfront.net/00722.jpg" width="640" height="480" BORDER=0></PIC></PICTURE><PICTURE ID="11"><ID>11</ID><PIC>&lt;IMG SRC="https://d1.cloudfront.net/01123.jpg" width="640" height="480" BORDER=0></PIC></PICTURE><PICTURE ID="2"><ID>2</ID><PIC>&lt;IMG SRC="https://d1.cloudfront.net/00224.jpg" width="640" height="480" BORDER=0></PIC></PICTURE><PICTURE ID="9"><ID>9</ID><PIC>&lt;IMG SRC="https://d1.cloudfront.net/00925.jpg" width="640" height="480" BORDER=0></PIC></PICTURE></OBJEKT>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($content);
$valuesPICtn = $xml->xpath("//OBJEKT//PICTURE");
$display = '';
foreach ($valuesPICtn as $PICelements) {
    $display .= '<li>';
    $display .= ''.$PICelements->PIC.'';
    $display .= '</li>';
}
echo "<ul>";
echo $display;
echo "</ul>";
```

You just need to filter all as occurrences with this **$valuesPICtn = $xml->xpath("/OBJEKT//PICTURE");**

and then then

```
foreach ($valuesPICtn the $PICelements) {
...
```

Comment: Hello Julio, your code works good. The thing what is my problem is, i need only the URL from the PIC element without &lt;IMG SRC= and width="640" height="480" BORDER=0>. Only the URL like "https://d1.cloudfront.net/00722.jpg"

Comment: I am very happy to help.
Ich helfe sehr gerne.

Comment: If you notice, the <img src="https://d1.cloudfront.net/00722.jpg" width="640" height="480" border="0"> is already correct.
Take a look at https://upwork.codefusiontm.com/stack/004, I left the program running there and you can inspect in the browser.

Comment: what I notice is that the url address, is not from a valid server at least for me shows dns problem.

Comment: yes the url´s is only for test. I need the clean URL´s without width, height ... for other functions in my page.

Comment: i understood, use this: $img = preg_replace( '/(width|height)="\d*"\s/', "", $PICelements->PIC );

Comment: YES Julio we come the solution near , your code work good. It must delete the <img , src= , border, > also. I dont understand the "\d*"\s/', "", how you now this?

Comment: The search is like this, search for width or height with = double quotes opens " + digits \d close double quotes " including white space \s, that is, is understood both width="640", and height="480", for example.

Comment: If i try that code with border included  '$display .= $img = preg_replace( '/(width|height|border)="\d*"\s/', "", $PICelements->PIC );' it works anymore , it leave the border inside.

Comment: No, to work use this preg_replace( '/(width|height|border)=("\d*"|\d*)/i', "", $PICelements->PIC );

Comment: See, same condition after = "\d*" OR \d* because your border not have double quotes and is uppercase, than /i to ignore case. That way, everything works!

Comment: Amazing, but the other like <img, src= , > cant delete with this code?

Comment: Cool, no because after equal sign the content is not numeric, remember \d to digits.

Comment: i feel my code ends in chaos ' $display .= $img = preg_replace( '/[^=]*=([^&]*).*//(width|height|border)=("\d*"|\d*)/i', "", $PICelements->PIC );' i cant get the result ):     'https://d1.cloudfront.net/00722.jpg'

Comment: i didn't understand your modification, this pattern is for another XML? If not, what's the idea?

Comment: this pattern is for this XML, i still try to get the clean URL like "https://d1.cloudfront.net/00722.jpg" without any other arround like <img or scr=

Comment: ahh, ok ok! I just get it, i'm sorry about that! To isolate the content src, you must use preg_match('/src="([^")*)"/i', $PICelements->PIC, $result); var_dump($result[1]);